# Проверка сайта на вирусы

Tags: антивирус

От хостинга пришло уведомление

> В результате антивирусной проверки вашего сайта, в относящихся к нему файлах обнаружен подозрительный программный код.

Проверил сайт через virustotal.com - говорит все ок.
Скачал весь сайт через фтп какой программой я могу его проверить на вредоносный код?

Comment: Обычно должны указывать в каком файле обнаружен подозрительный код. Иначе это попахивает разводом.

Comment: Ручками и глазками. Восстанови из бекапа и не парься. Проверка исходников на вирусы - это всё фигня.

Comment: Старый движок - много страниц кода - глаза не бесконечные.

Comment: Ну, а что делать? Антивирус тебе, скорее всего, ничем не поможет, т.к. способов наделать тебе в сайте дыр существует бесконечное множество.

Comment: Дыры в сайте мне не нужны, я имел ввиду php-шеллы и прочий вредоносный код

Comment: Дык php-шеллы может тебе наделать хоть сам вордпресс в штатной поставке.